# npm login via a node docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I'm trying to dockerize a project. I've got a few services as containers, i.e. Redis, Postgres, RabbitMQ, and Node. I have a `docker-compose.yml` that has all the services needed.

In my node build Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16

ARG PAT

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
COPY .npmrc /root/.npmrc
RUN npm install

COPY . .

WORKDIR /app/project1
RUN npm install

WORKDIR /app/project2
RUN npm install
```

The above fails because, within project2, I have a private GitHub package that I need to authenticate. I have generated a PAT and I can do `npm login --scope=@OWNER --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com` enter the correct credentials and then do `npm install` which successfully gets the package that needed authenticating.

Is there a way to automate this via docker-compose/Dockerfile? Somehow add the token, owner, username, etc to the .yml file and use that to login?

My node  services in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  node:
    container_name: node
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: ./docker/build/node/Dockerfile
      args:
        PAT: TOKEN
    ports:
      - 3150:3150
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you need your credentials in the build phase of your image. You can do as follows.

Create a `.npmrc` in your docker context

```
@OWNER:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${PAT}
user.email=email@example.com
user.name=foo bar
```

and copy that file in the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM  node:16-alpine
ARG PAT
COPY --chown=node .npmrc /home/node/.npmrc
```

and then during the image build set the value for the `PAT` environment variable from the `GITHUB_PAT` environment variable of the host.

```
docker build --build-arg PAT=${GITHUB_PAT} .
```

ie [`--build-arg`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options) sets the environment variables during build time of the image. But be aware, that any environment variable set via `--build-args` is only available during build time of the image. Ie, it's not available when the container is running. But again, you don't seem to need it at the runtime of the container, as the installation of your npm packages happens during the build time of the image.

Comment: Is there any reason why my `.npmrc` does not copy into my container? I've tested with a text file and that seems to be fine but no `.npmrc` was found in the target location. I've also done the args via my `docker-compose.yml` file. I've added `args` within my node service build and added the value of `PAT` in there. I then run `docker-compose up -d --build`. From what I understand, this functions the same way, right?

Comment: Don't know why the `.npmrc` is not copied. Maybe files starting with a `.` are not covered by `COPY . .` ... But I forgot to add the `ARG PAT` in the dockerfile ... Need this to define the `PAT` environment variable during build. Yes setting the environment variable in the `docker-compose.yaml` should be fine ...

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. I've just updated my question to include my node service from my `docker-compose.yml` file but I can't see anything that's wrong with it. It still fails to authenticate and `.npmrc` is no where to be found for some reason.

Comment: You are not setting any `WORKDIR` prior to copying the `.npmrc` file, thus `COPY .npmrc .npmrc` copies the file to the root directory `/`  of the image. But it has to be located in the home folder of the user executing the `npm install` command. In my case it's the `node` user so I copy it to `/home/node/.npmrc` In your case it may also be the `root` user of the image, then you need to copy it to `/root/.npmrc`

Comment: I did have `WORKDIR /app` at the top of my Dockerfile. My mistake, I missed this out while typing it. I missed your the chown you've added in your example, i'll try that.